# Quicksort cannot handle small numbers?

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

I am using quicksort to sort data from an FFT function so I can find use interquartile range to find outliers. At the moment, I am not sure about why the data that has gone through the quicksort is not really sorted. Here is the function I used (modified to use doubles):

```
void quickSort(double arr[], int left, int right) {
  int i = left, j = right;
  int tmp;
  double pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

  /* partition */
  while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i] < pivot)
              i++;
        while (arr[j] > pivot)
              j--;
        if (i <= j) {
              tmp = arr[i];
              arr[i] = arr[j];
              arr[j] = tmp;
              i++;
              j--;
        }
  };

  /* recursion */
  if (left < j)
        quickSort(arr, left, j);
  if (i < right)
        quickSort(arr, i, right);
  }
```

I am not sure how to put the output here, as it is quite long. Here is how all the unsorted data pretty much looks like:

```
0.01033861 0.00861337 0.00861337 -0.00326733 -0.00326733 0.00098514 0.00098514 -0.01022199 -0.01022199 -0.00303045 -0.00303045 -0.00435644 -0.00435644 -0.00217089 -0.00217089 -0.00171707 -0.00171707 -0.00073572 -0.00073572 -0.00283767 -0.00283767 0.00008432 0.00008432 -0.00288364 -0.00288364 -0.00162750 -0.00162750 -0.00222617 -0.00222617 -0.00017057 -0.00017057 0.00101272 0.00101272 0.00332283 0.00332283 -0.00115711 -0.00115711
```

It does not seem like the sorting is right, since most of the output consists of extremely small data (0.00000000), and the rest has spots that look like this:

```
0.00000000 0.00000000 -0.00002053 0.00000000 -0.00002051 -0.00002051 -0.00002050 0.00000000 -0.00002048 0.00000000 -0.00002045 -0.00002039 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 -0.00002025 0.00000000 -0.00002020 0.00000000 -0.00002019 0.00000000 0.00000000 -0.00002005 0.00000000
```

Here what I did in order to get this output:

```
 int size = sizes[i];
 int numElements = (int)pow(2.0, ceil(log((double)size)/log(2.0))); //next power of 2
 double *X = (double *) malloc((2*numElements+1) * sizeof(double));
 double *p = ptr[i]; //ptr[i] is a void *ptr;

 //X is filled with data
 for (j = 0; j < size; j++){ //put numbers in
    if ((double)*(p+j) < 1000 && (double)*(p+j) > -1000) {
        X[2*j+1] = (double)*(p+j);
    } else{
        X[2*j+1] = 0.0;
    }
    X[2*j+2] = 0.0;
 }
 for (j = size; j < numElements; j++){ //fill the rest with zeros
     X[2*j+1] = 0.0;
     X[2*j+1] = 0.0;
 }

 printf("\nStarting FFT()..."); fflush(stdout);
 four1(X, numElements, 1, pData);
 for (j = 0; j < numElements; j++){
      //first block of data is printed
      fprintf(pData->pFile, "%.8f %.8f ", X[2*j+1], X[2*j+1]);
  }

 //create a copy of the array for storage
 double *array = (double *) malloc((maxIndex-minIndex+1) * sizeof(double));
 for (j = 0; j < maxIndex-minIndex+1; j++){
    array[j] = X[2*(j+minIndex)+1];
 }

 quickSort(X, 1, 2*(long)size+2); //don't need to sort everything

 //print out the output of the quicksort
 for (j = 1; j < 2*(long)size+2; j++){
     //second block of data is printed
     fprintf(pData->pFile2, "%.8f ", X[j]);
 }

 //use interquartile range
 double q1, q3, iqr;
 q1 = X[(long)size/2+1]; //size is even
 q3 = X[3*(long)size/2+1];
 iqr = q3-q1;
 printf("q1: %.5f, q3: %.5f, iqr: %.5f", q1, q3, iqr);

 //check if any of the elements in array[] are outliers
 for (j = 0; j < maxIndex-minIndex+1; j++) {
      if (array[j] > 3*(q3+iqr)/2){
            printf(" A match!"); fflush(stdout);
            break;
      }
  }
```

Why is the sorting not working as it should?

Comment: You need to post the code directly in the question instead of just through a link.

Comment: I have no idea what the data you posted even means, but if your sort algorithm is outputting different data than the input then it's broken. Obviously, we can't tell you what's broken if we can't see **your** code. Sample code found on some web site doesn't count.

Comment: There is a library function called `qsort`, in case you missed it.

Comment: @user3386109 : except that it doesn't necessarily use quick sort. ;)

Comment: `Here's the function I use (c/c++).` - if that's literally true, no wonder you get odd results as that one is for ints.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar LOL yeah, sometimes it uses a faster algorithm. I hate it when that happens :)

Comment: It looks like it's sorting high-to-low in all cases (ignoring the last one, with the NaNs since they aren't likely to sort properly anyway).  Is that what you wanted?  Or did you want low-to-high?

Comment: Updated my question. Haha that int-double was a pretty bad mistake. Also, @TomKarzes the problem is that I did not have any NaNs or big negative numbers in my unsorted data. For what I got in the most recent run of my program, I also do not have that many 0s in my unsorted data.

Comment: Just re-ran it and the sort's odd numbers mysteriously went away (I also changed tmp in quickSort() into a double). Maybe it's because I restarted my computer...? Anyways, thanks to everyone! I'll keep these tips for next time c:

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Actually I could not find the exact problem in your program, but if you want a program to perform quicksort on an array of elements, this is it:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void quicksort(int [10],int,int);

int main(){
  int x[20],size,i;

  printf("Enter size of the array: ");
  scanf("%d",&size);

  printf("Enter %d elements: ",size);
  for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    scanf("%d",&x[i]);

  quicksort(x,0,size-1);

  printf("Sorted elements: ");
  for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    printf(" %d",x[i]);

  return 0;
}

void quicksort(int x[10],int first,int last){
    int pivot,j,temp,i;

     if(first<last){
         pivot=first;
         i=first;
         j=last;

         while(i<j){
             while(x[i]<=x[pivot]&&i<last)
                 i++;
             while(x[j]>x[pivot])
                 j--;
             if(i<j){
                 temp=x[i];
                  x[i]=x[j];
                  x[j]=temp;
             }
         }

         temp=x[pivot];
         x[pivot]=x[j];
         x[j]=temp;
         quicksort(x,first,j-1);
         quicksort(x,j+1,last);

    }
}
```

You can check it's [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).

It has the algorithm's of all different types of quick sorts. Just to give more clarity, se the animations:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The indices for c normally go from 0 to n-1, and that is the way you have the quicksort function coded. The call should be:

```
    quickSort(X, 0, 2*(long)size + 1);  /* changed the +2 to +1 */
```

I'm not sure what size represents or why you multiply by 2, normally size is the number of elements to be sorted in which case the call is:

```
    quickSort(X, 0, size - 1);
```

Comment: it's pretty much the same output, but thanks for answering :3

Comment: @himty - I don't see where X[] is initialized.

Comment: I left it out because it's a bit complicated. I can add it in though.